# drag and drop from preview in Big Sur

Tags: finder, big-sur, preview

On Catalina, if I had a file open in Preview I could attach it to an email by dragging the little icon next to the filename at the top of the window. Now that I've upgraded to Big Sur, that little icon is no longer there.

Is there an equivalent to that feature in Big Sur? That is, if I have a document open in Preview, can I quickly drag the file into another document without first having to navigate to it in Finder?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer just after posting the question: if you click on the file name at the top of the window the little icon appears next to it, and you can drag-and-drop that as before.